# observe scroll offset via UIScrollView delegate scrollViewDidScroll when scrolling programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiviewanimation

I have a UIScrollView which i scroll programmatically using the below code:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 10.0, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseInOut) { [weak self] in
        self?.scrollView.setContentOffset(someOffset, animated: false)
      } completion: { [weak self] (finished) in
        // do something
}
```

The scrolling and animation works fine, however the `scrollViewDidScroll` delegate function is called just once when the scrolling is done programatically.

I need to be able to observe the position of the scroll and trigger something as different offset points are reached and the UIScrollView will only be scrolled programatically.

How can this be achieved using `scrollViewDidScroll` or any other way for that matter ?

Comment: I think you need to provide a bit more detail about what you need to *"trigger"*. Generally speaking, I think it's assumed that if you are programmatically running an animation, you would also be running code to "do something" during the animation. Also, if you're scrolling 100-pts over 10-seconds you may take a different approach than if you're scrolling 5,000-pts over 10-seconds.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am scrolling a big image and since the images are not from my app bundle, so the height of the image can be anything. While it won't be 100pts but it could be any random distance above 1000 pts as the user loads their image. At specific points, I would load a type of annotation or hint. I have tried to run a timer simultaneously with the animation but that is not too accurate.

Comment: @ShawnFrank not sure if this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68109661/4833705 will help your situation but it helped me tremendously for scrolling videos in my cv feed. I'm able to find the % of the cell on screen and can play/pause videos as the user scrolls. The answer works perfectly for me. Hope that it helps