# Determine Percentage of Visibility of Horizontal CollectionView Cells on Screen

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiscrollview

I have a horizontal collectionView. There will always be 2 cells side by side, they both have the same width and height. The cells plays videos and when scrolling I want to load the video for the next cell that is 70% on screen and stop the video for the cell that is less than that. I found several similar questions but everything seems to reference 1 cell.

1- Cells 59 and 60 are both 100% on screen

[image]

2- Scrolling left, 59 is still more than 70%, 60 is 100%, and 61 is less than 30% on screen

[image]

3- Still scrolling left, 59 is less than 30% on screen, 60 is 100%, and 61 is more than 70%

[image]

Anything that is is already visible as in cell 59 in the first two photos and 60 in all three photos, I have logic to prevent the cell from loading again even though `cell.loadNewVideo()` will run for them.

```
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2
    return CGSize(width: width, height: 150)
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    collectionView.visibleCells.forEach { cell in
        guard let cell = cell as? VideoCell else { continue }

        guard let indexPath = collectionView.indexPath(for: cell) else { return }
        guard let layoutAttributes = collectionView.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath) else { return }
        let cellFrameInSuperview = collectionView.convert(layoutAttributes.frame, to: collectionView.superview)
        guard let superView = collectionView.superview else { return }
        let convertedRect = collectionView.convert(cellFrameInSuperview, to: superView)
        let intersect = collectionView.frame.intersection(convertedRect)

        if intersect.width > (UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2) * 0.7 {

            cell.loadNewVideo()

        } else {

            cell.destroyOldVideo()
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried the same code `scrollViewWillEndDragging` in but it also didn't work:

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {

}
```

Comment: You know to use scrollViewDidScroll so what's the issue?

Comment: It's giving inaccurate results. For example right now I scrolled from 59 and now 60 and 61 are fully visible. I added print statements and it says that 59 isn't visible (destroy) but it also says that 60 isn't visible but 60 is fully on screen with 61. It does say 61 is visible. Sometimes when I scroll from 61 to 62, and they are both fully visible on screen, it will say that 61 is visible but 62 isn't.

Comment: Well one question is why are you looking at the layout attributes? Just look at where the cell is. That is after all what you want to know. The way to find out whether a cell is on the screen is to compare the cell frame in screen coordinates with the screen bounds. You are asking some other rather tricky question instead.

Comment: How else can i find out where the cell is? From what I've read that is the way to find out where the cell is located. How can i fine out the % of the visible cell without using that?

Comment: The cell is a view. The window is a view. This is simple stuff. Why make it complicated?

Comment: hmmmmm, I didn't think of it that way. That makes sense. After I get the cell's position and size in the window, how do i compare that the to % that I am looking for? `let keyWindow = ... let rectInWindow = collectionView.convert(cell.center, to: keyWindow)`

Comment: Convert the rect of the cell frame into window internal coordinates and intersect that rect with the window bounds. Compare the area of the intersection to the area of the cell frame. That's your percentage. Keep it simple.

Comment: ok. I'm working on another bug. As soon as I'm done I'll try it and get back to you. Thanks as usual!!!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are *way* overthinking this. Forget about `layoutAttributes` and all that fancy-pants stuff and just do what you said you wanted to do: find out how much of *the cell* is *onscreen*.

The cell is a view. The screen (represented, let's say, by the window) is a view. Intersect them! Look at the intersection of the cell's frame with the window (or whatever), in appropriately converted coordinates, to get the part of the cell that is onscreen, and compare its size with the cell's frame's size. That is your percentage. Now do anything you like that percentage.

In this example, "anything you like" is just to *display* the percentage.

[image]

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let cells = self.collectionView.visibleCells
    for cell in cells {
        let f = cell.frame
        let w = self.view.window!
        let rect = w.convert(f, from: cell.superview!)
        let inter = rect.intersection(w.bounds)
        let ratio = (inter.width * inter.height) / (f.width * f.height)
        let rep = (String(Int(ratio * 100)) + "%")
        let label = cell.contentView.subviews.first as! UILabel
        label.text = rep
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that if you are doing any other fancy-pants stuff, like transforms, that will violate the frame, so keep that in mind when doing your calculations.

Comment: Nice! I love the animation. I haven't had a chance to try it yet but I already know that it works. Thanks. "fancy-pants stuff" lmaoooooo, so true!

Comment: Can I just say this is brilliant, but I have no idea how to use it to trigger a function when a cell reaches 100%. How do you detect which cells index has reached 100% Any ideas?

Comment: @Chris you check which cell's ratio has reached 100% and then do collectionView.indexPath(for: cell).

Comment: @Soberman I never thought of that. Would have loved to have used this but found a different solution in the end