# Check table view cell fully visible

Tags: swift, uitableview

how are you

I need to know how can i determine table view cell fully visible for playing auto play movie in cell and also detect hiding the table view cell.

I have apply this code below in table view but not give me the correct solution.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt   indexPath: IndexPath) {
   let cellRect = tableView.rectForRow(at: indexPath)
   let isFullyVisible = tableView.bounds.contains(rectInFull)
   if isFullyVisible {
    // Play video
   } 
}
```

So please can you tell me how can i get the correct table view cell visible

Answer (score 1):

cell.frame.origin.y >= tableview.contentOffset.y && cell.frame.origin.y + cell.frame.size.height <= tableview.contentOffset.y + tableview.bounds.size.height

Comment: I found the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24825994/play-video-on-uitableviewcell-when-it-is-completely-visible

Comment: @HamzaAlmass Thanks for your link. But I see the key point, the judgement of visibility condition, is the same as what I've pointed out. : )

Comment: It's not work , you can also check this is best answer from matt https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68108188/determine-percentage-of-visibility-of-horizontal-collectionview-cells-on-screen

Comment: @HamzaAlmass It doesn’t work, because you check it in a wrong system hook. If in didScroll, It will be fine.

Comment: @HamzaAlmass And of course, you could convert view coordination, that’s your choice. In a table view, cell will not scroll  in horizontal axis. So checking vertical axis is fairly enough. See the thing inside, not just the code.

Comment: So you could mark your problem as duplicated. : )

Answer (score 0):

You might want to implement the `UIScrollViewDelegate` method `scrollViewDidScroll(_:)` and in there you could do the check for visible cells in your table view:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScollView) {
      guard let tv = scrollView as? UITableView else { return }
      
      tv.visibleCells.forEach { $0.playVideo() }
}
```

Of course assuming that method on the cell (`playVideo()`) exists and it takes care of being called multiple times when the video is already playing (i.e. must ignore the call if is already playing).
Otherwise if you need the `indexPaths` of visible cells or any fine tuning use either the property `indexPathsForVisibleRows` or the method `indexPathForRows(in:)` on the table view, then those index paths you'll optionally obtain inside an array will point to the model's objects (which might implement the *play video* logic).

Comment: I found the solution here I found the solution here stackoverflow.com/questions/24825994/… – 
Hamza Almass
 just now   Edit

Comment: If the cell is partial visible at the edge of the tableview bounds, the cell will also be in the `visibleCells`, I think.

Comment: @Neal.Marlin as I mentioned in my reply there is also the method ‘indexPathsForRows(in:)’ that could be adopted, or eventually ‘visibleCells’ could also be filtered by those having their frame completely contained inside ‘visibleRect’ property of the table view. No matter the detail granularity, I still think the approach of implementing UIScrollViewDelegate’s ‘didScroll’ method is the best suiting this case.